# How to convert Linux ISO into VHD für Azure

Tags: azure, vhd, iso

I have a Custom ISO inside a Blob Storage-Account and want to convert this file into a VHD to create a Azure-VM. Is there a official tutorial for it? Google is not a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Azure does not have any tooling to convert an ISO to a VHD. You would need to use the ISO file to create  a VHD image using something like Hyper-V on your desktop, or other conversion tools. Once you have it in VHD format it can be used to create a VM in Azure.